# How to disable a button from PHP using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, disable

I have a button on the login Page and its working perfectly from the PHP side, but I'd like to disable the button once it's clicked

I've tried echoing a script with the function to disable it.

I'm using the same method to disable other button and it works, and when I add onclick to the button it works but it disables the submit feature.

How can I keep the submit feature and also use the javascript function?

NOTE: Javascript file and the PHP file are two different files.

PHP

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST)) {
    if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
    'console.log("Were here")',
    'disableLoginButton()',
    '</script>';

    header("Location:NextPage.php");
    }
  }
}
?>
```

HTML

```
<form>
<div class="row">
<label>Username</label>
<input type="text">
</div>

<div class="row">
<label>Username</label>
<input type="text">
</div>

<button type="submit" id="button">
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function disableLoginButton(){
const loginButton = document.getElementById("loginButton");
loginButton.classList.toggle('buttonHover');
loginButton.classList.toggle('disabled');

console.log("Hello there");
loginButton.disabled = true;
}
```

CSS

```
button:disabled{
  cursor: none;
  background-color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
  color:rgb(53, 53, 53);
}

.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Comment: You need to do it in an `onSubmit()` function in the page, I think. By the time your PHP is running, the page has gone unless you're submitting with Ajax. What does actually submit your form? I don't see an action tag, nor a `method="post"` tag.

Comment: By saying you want to disable the button, what exactly are you trying to achieve here? Do you want the button to be disabled, when you click on the button, so you are not able to accidently send the form twice? Or do you want the PHP response to have a diabled button?

Also, how do you combine the PHP and HTML files?

Comment: I'm submitting the form through a API call and from the response it moves onto the next page

Comment: @AmrGadalla Could you elaborate more on this?

Comment: Then surely you would call your disable-button function as part of that block of code, which is presumably in Javascript?

Comment: I want to disable the button in a way that the form can't be submitted twice, and the hover is disabled and the mouse cursor on the button changes.

Comment: @droopsnoot I've tried added the javascript function call in php that disables the button, but always gives me error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" when console.log is before the function call it shows other than that it both don't work.

Comment: @droopsnoot I've tried also added a script tag and putting that within the HTML file and also same issue. and I've tried straight up added the conditions into the script tag in the PHP script but also same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to react at client side to the pressing of the button to disable is, not on at server side.

```js
function onSubmit(e) {
  disableLoginButton();
}

function disableLoginButton() {
  const loginButton = document.getElementById("login-button");

  console.log("Hello there");
  loginButton.disabled = true;
}

document.getElementById('login-form').addEventListener('submit', onSubmit)
```

```css
button:disabled {
  cursor: none;
  background-color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
  color: rgb(53, 53, 53);
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<form id="login-form">
  <div class="row">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" id="login-button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: How can I include the PHP script to validate the Form?

Comment: @AmrGadalla That shout be a different question

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can echo script which exist in different php file using form submits (You might use Ajax for it)

Do something like this

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST)) {
    if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
    'console.log("Were here")',
    'disableLoginButton()',
    '</script>';

    header("Location:NextPage.php");//Actually no point of disabling button when u do this
    }
  }
}
?>
<form action="" method="post"><!-- Submitting to same page-->
<div class="row">
<label>Username</label>
<input type="text">
</div>

<div class="row">
<label>Username</label>
<input type="text">
</div>

<button type="submit" id="loginButton">
</form>
<script>
function disableLoginButton(){
const loginButton = document.getElementById("loginButton");
loginButton.classList.toggle('buttonHover');
loginButton.classList.toggle('disabled');

console.log("Hello there");
loginButton.disabled = true;
}
</script>
```

Keeping php script in same page and submitting form to same page will permit php file access html elements and javascript functions in your case `disableLoginButton()`

If you want the form to be submitted to some other page (backend page) and you want to disable the `button` there is no point as **Form submit actually redirects to action page** so your login page will not be visible anymore. But there are some other ways you can do it.

That's all from my point for now.